# How to access the context inside an Ember.View?

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to get the record ID from the underlying object set on the view object, so I can set it on the view's HTML wrapper. Here's what I'm trying:

```
// Row in record editing table view.
views.RecordActionTableRowView = Ember.View.extend({
  // Does not work.
  attributeBindings: ['record_id:data-record-id'],
  templateName: 'pult-record-action-table-row',

  init: function () {
    console.log(this);
    // Does not work either. Undefined.
    console.log(this.get('record_id'));
    // Does not work either. Undefined.
    console.log(this.record);
    return this._super();
  }
});
```

This view is called from a template, so its own template contains the right data, but I can't find it inside the view code. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle stating your problem? From the posted code it seems kind of impossible to know what's going on. What does your template look like? How is the record set? You can use this as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/DvdVH/

Comment: Well, the exact example is hardly relevant here. I'm just trying to figure out if there's a general way of getting access to the template context from within a view. There's nothing in the documentation about it. There's supposedly a context attribute on the view, but that is also undefined.

Comment: could you first call _super(), and then the log stuff ?

Comment: As @pangratz said you need to at least post the template. You can access template variables in the `templateVariables` property, if that's what you look for. See here: http://emberjs.com/guides/view_layer/#toc_accessing-template-variables-from-views

Comment: Hmm, `templateVariables` is also undefined, so there's probably something bad going on here. Setting up an accurate test case for this is probably going to take at least half a day of work, so I'll just have to work around it for now.

Comment: If I understand what you're asking you need to call this.get('context') to get what you're looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want `this.get('context')` or `this.get('content')`. In some circumstances, checking this within `didInsertElement` may be better than in `init`, in case the view is created before `context` is set.

Answer (score 0):

I justfaced same issue trying to access what is described in documentation as templateVariables in my case the following worked

```
this.get("templateData.keywords.myvarname")
```

Comment: This is not public API and should be avoided.

Comment: I fully agree with you @LukeMelia however what is in Public Api seems not working ... [doc](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/#toc_accessing-template-variables-from-views)